# How do you add an UIImage to a MSMutableArray in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have noob objective-c question. How do you add an UIImage to a MSMutableArray? Here is the code that I have:

```
MSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIImage *image;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextSize);
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, pushUpSize);

    [screenWindow.layer renderInContext: context];  
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[arr addObject:image];
```

But this crashes the program when it tries to add the image. I read somewhere that its adding a variable but not the pointer, is that correct? How do I add the UIImage to the array, its an object isn't it?

Thanks!

Comment: What does it show in the log when it crashes? Please post that so that we can help you more on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@thiesdiggity: Not much is wrong in your code from what I can see. But just try out the below code as I think the `image` object is `nil`:

```
MSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIImage *image;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextSize);
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, pushUpSize);

    [screenWindow.layer renderInContext: context];  
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

if(image != nil)
{
    [arr addObject:image];
}
```

Let me know if you need more help and please post your crash log for more help

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You are initializing the array `arr` but adding the images to the (apparently unitialized) array `imageArr`.</s>

Based on your updated code, I would say that the `image` object is probably `nil`.  Calling `addObject:` with a `nil` value is specifically prohibited in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).